Old Film from the late 60's or 70's. Maybe Chinese or french. Femme Fatale
I have just seen one 5 minutes or so long scene from this film like 5 years ago, I can't remember the language or if it was dubbed. The movie was in color, it looked old, like "1000 eyes of sumuru" era. I think the female was asian, though not sure, She is wearing a black veil if I remember correctly and she is on a rocking chair, a clown or mime is going down on her, a guy (her accomplice or lover) is watching through an air vent, she ends up killing the clown with her thighs (choking via squeeze, not neck break) and kicking his body away when he is dead. The 2 dump the clown's body in a river or creek and watch him float away.

Seems like this is the Pink Film Watcher in the Attic from 1976. From an online synopsis:

A young man (Renji Ishibashi) who despises any personal interactions with his neighbors routinely sneaks into the attic through a crawlspace in his closet and spies on the lives of his fellow tenants through knotholes in the ceiling. [...]  the man is uncovered while gazing upon a woman (Junko Miyashita) having sex with a man dressed as clown. Enraptured by the thrill of being spied upon, the woman kills her suitor, strangling him with her thighs 

